# asyncio queue.get() gets stuck

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-3.6

I am working on a project that needs to do some tasks asynchronously, but I am limited to using the least amount of extra subprocesses, for that I decided to have 2 processes: `dispatcher_p` and `worker_p`. Since I am making use of the async library I have two async tasks: `async_worker` and `async_task`. The program works as follows:

1. `worker_p` starts the event loop with a single task: `async_worker`
2. `dispatcher_p` waits on a *queue* for incoming data
3. `dispatcher_p` adds data to an *async_queue* via `put_nowait()`
4. `async_worker` which is awaiting the *async_queue* gets the data and starts a task using `async_task` and calls *task_done()*
5. For simplicity `async_task` just sleeps for 3 seconds and exits.

For simplicity lets strip out the sub task that `async_worker` should start, leaving us with the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio

async def task_worker(aq):
    while True:
        task = await aq.get()
        if task is not None:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            aq.task_done()
        else:
            break

def dispatcher_p(ev_l, q, async_q):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(ev_l)
    while True:
        task = q.get()
        if task is not None:
            async_q.put_nowait(task)
        else:
            async_q.put(None)
            break

def worker_p(ev_l, aq):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(ev_l)
    ev_l.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task_worker(aq)))
    ev_l.close()

q = mp.Queue()

def put_task(data):
    q.put(data)

def init():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    aq = asyncio.Queue()

    p1 = mp.Process(target=worker_p, args=(event_loop, aq,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=dispatcher_p, args=(event_loop, q, aq))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    # Test
    put_task("hi")
    put_task("bye")
    put_task("test")
    put_task(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

The problem is that even though `task_worker` is running in the event_loop, it freezes at `task = await aq.get()`. Why does this happen? I still don't understand how asyncio works across several processes.

Comment: asyncio.Queue is for asyncio, not for inter-process communication.

Comment: If you can run on Py3.2+ this might be a lot easier: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Answer (score 1):

For the record

The design of this script is flawed!

Things to consider:

1. The script creates 2 child processes and passes them a reference to the mp Queue and the async Queue.
2. Even though they report the same object id via python's `id()`, they seem to be running in different memory contexts, thus unable to communicate with each another

The reason `await aq.get()` gets stuck is that even though we're adding elements to the async queue passed to process 1, the async queue in process 2 is unable to see/get notified of that.

The solution is to use a multiprocessing queue for inter-process communication and an async queue within the same process. Using an async queue across processes does not work the way you'd expect and it's WRONG!

You can see this more clearly by printing the state of the async queue to console:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio

async def task_worker(aq:asyncio.Queue):
    print('ASYNC: Started')
    while True:
        print(f'ASYNC: Get info from async queue. {aq.qsize()}')
        task = await aq.get()
        if task is not None:
            print(f'ASYNC: Work on task asynchronously: {task}')
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            aq.task_done()
        else:
            print('ASYNC: Sentinel, end async worker')
            break
    print('ASYNC: Task done?')

def dispatcher_p(ev_l, q, async_q:asyncio.Queue):
    print('DISPATCHER: Started')
    asyncio.set_event_loop(ev_l)
    while True:
        print('DISPATCHER: Get task from mp queue')
        task = q.get()
        if task is not None:
            print(f'DISPATCHER: Work on task: {task}')
            async_q.put_nowait(task)
            print(f'DISPATCHER: Async queue size: {async_q.qsize()}')
        else:
            print('DISPATCHER: Sentinel, send None')
            async_q.put_nowait(None)
            break
    print('DISPATCHER: Dispatcher ended')

def worker_p(ev_l, aq):
    print('WORKER: Started')
    asyncio.set_event_loop(ev_l)
    print('WORKER: Wait until loop ends')
    ev_l.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task_worker(aq)))
    print('WORKER: Loop ended')
    ev_l.close()
    print('WORKER: Loop closed')
    print('WORKER: Worker ended')

q = mp.Queue()

def put_task(data):
    q.put(data)

def init():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    aq = asyncio.Queue()

    p1 = mp.Process(target=worker_p, args=(event_loop, aq,))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=dispatcher_p, args=(event_loop, q, aq))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    # Test
    put_task("hi")
    put_task("bye")
    put_task("test")
    put_task(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```